# Adding custom named colors generated by Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css, tailwind-3, tailwind-variants

Is there a way to assign custom colors in a way that allows Tailwind to generate meaningful semantic names?

For example, I'd like to have a collection of `success` colors that can be applied like this:

- `bg-success` => Tailwind generates `#F6FFED` behind the scene
- `border-success` => Tailwind generates `#B7EB8F`
- `text-success` => Tailwind generates `#135200`
- ... and so on

### Update

Here's what I ended up doing but not sure if it's the best approach.

```js
module.exports = {
  content: [...],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      backgroundColor: ({ theme }) => ({
        error: theme('colors.red.100'),
        info: theme('colors.blue.100'),
        success: theme('colors.green.100'),
        warning: theme('colors.gold.100'),
      }),
      borderColor: ({ theme }) => ({
        error: theme('colors.red.300'),
        info: theme('colors.blue.300'),
        success: theme('colors.green.300'),
        warning: theme('colors.gold.300'),
      }),
      textColor: ({ theme }) => ({
        error: theme('colors.red.900'),
        info: theme('colors.blue.900'),
        success: theme('colors.green.900'),
        warning: theme('colors.gold.900'),
      }),
    },
  },
  plugins: [...],
}
```

With that implementation, I am able to then recall generated colors I outlined in my question above.

```js
  <div class="bg-success border-success text-success border-2">
    Hello world!
  </div>
```

But again, I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all you need to do is update your tailwind.config.js file and extend the colors with your custom color needs. Here's an example of what you may be trying to do:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  extend: {
    colors: {
      'success': '#00FF00',
    },
  },
}
```

And then in your markup, you can do things like

`<div class="bg-success"> ABCD </div>`
or
`<p class="text-success"> Hello World! </p>`.

Should definitely work!

Comment: Thanks for the response. But it's not quite what I was asking. Notice in my question, I specified that `bg-success` and `text-success` each should produce a different color. The standard documented color extension doesn't do that.